# While uploading app to AppStore error with requested method validateSoftwareSPIUsage happened

Tags: ipa, xcode11, app-store-connect

I'm using new Xcode 11, trying to build an app for iOS 13.0 with heavy usage of On-demand Recources (so maybe that is the root of the problem). The application works and builds well on simulator, successfully compiles to .ipa file. But after I've started upload to AppStore I got this kind of error: [Screenshot from Xcode Organizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrzh9.jpg)
Which says:

> An error occurred while trying to call the requested method validateSoftwareSPIUsage.

I've checked it with two different developer accounts and got the same result, so the problem shouldn't be with my provisioning profile, or distribution certificate. I've tried to search it, but seems that even google doesn't know what it is. Appreciate you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what was the problem, I was violating [On-Demand Resource Sizes Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/PlatformSizesforOn-DemandResources.html).
 In my case application got more than 1000 asset packs. I dunno will the error message be the same if you violate other constrains, but I guess it's very possible.